# Is there a way to exclude template url keyword arguments from view function definition?

Tags: python, django

I have a url in my template that's routed in this way:

**workoutcal/templates/calendar.html:**

```
<a href="{% url 'workoutcal:add' year=table.0 month=table.1 day=element.0 %}" class="add">Add workout</a>
```

**workoutcal/urls.py:**

```
url(r'^add/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/$', views.add, name = 'add'), #Adding a workout for the date in question.
```

**workoutcal/views.py:**

```
def add(request,year,month,day):
    return HttpResponse("This is the add page")
```

If I replace `add()` with this:

```
def add(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is the add page")
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File 
"/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'
```

Meaning `views.add` had an unexpected keyword argument sent to it. Let's say that I want to pass these keyword arguments to the `url` in `calendar.html` because they're needed to get the correct url, but that I don't want to use these arguments in my view. Is there a way to exclude the arguments from the view function definition without getting this error?

Comment: I can't understand why you want to send the arguments in the URL but not use them in the view.

Comment: why do you have the date in the url if you're not using it for anything? it doesn't make sense

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's not the most useful question. I intend to use the dates, I simply asked out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def add(request,year=None,month=None,day=None):
```

make your view functions like this , as you need to pass the argument in urlpatterns or it will error out

Comment: you can pass them by storing them in session and access them in the other view you want to , but if you have urlpattern with args, then the view must have those keywords